# Spin tool problem

Tags: modeling

I want to rotate my object with spin tool 90 degrees to the left, which is not that complicated but when i try to give it a slight incline it leans a litle which i want to avoid. What should I do to prevent that?  [image][image][image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I didn't get ur question. Can u please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry english is not my native language...As you can see in pic 3, selected part(orange) is slightly rotated/leaned at one side after using spin tool unlike at pic 2, this does not happen when i spin at single axis...I wont to avoid this lean.

Comment: Looks like a problem with axes. Set the one you need to the desired value and others to 0.

Comment: @NikolaRadovic Can u show top-view and 3d cursor

Comment: @JacksonPro I added the top view photo

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth Yeah but i want this to spin to the left and up (those are two axis)

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth did u try moving the cursor in +x axis?

Comment: I didnt understood what do you mean? @JacksonPro

Comment: the only partial solution was to select vertices of the end after using the spin tool and to try to rotate them with proportional editing turned on

Comment: @NikolaRadovic Did u try moving the centre of the spin tool? also, did u try tweaking the options in the spin tool?

Comment: I added one last picture, here you can see what I mean. I tried everything but I think that this is how spin tool work and I cant change that

Answer (score 1):

Not directly answering your question, sorry, but typically, it would be simpler and less destructive, (much more flexible,) to model this kind of surface by sweeping a profile curve along a path curve, using the path curve's own 'Bevel (Object)' in its *Data* tab > *Geometry* panel:

[image]

(Profile scaled up for illustration)

The path curve would probably have its Twist method set to 'Z-Up'. It can be converted to a mesh when happy, for more convenient *Solidify*, *Bevel*, or *Subdivision* modifiers, if wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you previously used the spin tool and altered the y-axis. Revert this value back to zero instead of -0.32.

If it still does not fix the issue then there might be a rotation with the 3D cursor. In this case click N while hovering in the viewport and open the drop down menu of the 3D Cursor under the view tab and make all axis 0 in rotation.